# Pascal, I have to introduce a letter and number and using boolean to find the value of this sentence ,,This letter has the alphabetical order = N''

Tags: boolean, pascal

The problem should be solved with boolean. I have to introduce a letter and then a number, and to find with the sentence is true or false. for example if  i typed a and 1 it should be true. Also the capital letters also count. Sounds like a dumb and easy program but i really don t know how to do it. I don t really know where is the mistake but i think it is on the line 14, 15 and 16, where boolean is. When i run the program it doesn't show the right answer.

```
Program P14;
var N,m,y,e:integer;
    a:char;
    T,P,Q,Z:boolean;
begin
  writeln('type a letter '); readln(a);
  m:=ord(a);
  writeln('give a natural number N '); readln(N);
  e:=m-64;
  y:=m-96;
  P:=(64<m) and (m<91) or (96<m) and (m<123);
  writeln('it is a letter - ',P);
  Q:=(e<30) and (m<91) and (m>64);
  Z:=(y<30) and (m>96) and (m<123);
  T:= P=true and Q=true or  P=true and Z=true;
  writeln('This letter has the alphabetical order = N - ',T);
end.
```

Comment: You say: *...i really don t know how to do it*. How come? You show your code, what is wrong with it? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention and it s my first time asking on this site, everytime i run it  says false, for example if i put a and 1 the sentence is false, although it is true and i guess the problem is in the last 3 booleans

Comment: Which sentence is false and what should it say, and why? Please be specific! Oh, and please edit your question (see the Edit button beneath the tags) instead of adding info here in comments, thank you.

Comment: Line 14,15,16  idk why it is incorrect, pretty sure it is because i don t use the boolean correct

Comment: I'm just about to leave, sorry. No time. Check what those lines actually do. You can write an answer yourself if you find the error.

Comment: The last line: "writeln('This letter...order = N - ', T);" makes very little sense. Even if changed so that N would be the `var N` introduced on the second line, subtracting `T`, which is a boolean, is so wrong. Sorry, can't help you further as the task is unclear.

Comment: `T:= P=true and Q=true or  P=true and Z=true;` does not do what you think it does because of operator precedence - `or` is evaluated before `and`. As you have it written, it evaluates the entire line as one expression, instead of two separate tests. It should be `T := (P = true and Q = true) or (P = true and Z = true);`, or, because you're dealing with booleans, `T := (P and Q) or (P and Z);`. You can actually shorten it, because you're using `P` on both sides - `T := P and (Q or Z);`.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this when i will be home. Thanks. Have a great day.

Comment: Alright, i ll make sure to change that, thanks for trying to help